# I want to get search results on button click

Tags: android

I want to retrieve matched results from the existing list by entering a keyword on edit text and then enter a button. I am trying this code. but it doesn't work. Note that i want results on button click. Please sort out the issue.

```
edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);

     b. setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
                {


                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
                    {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    }



                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }



                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged( Editable arg0)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        SearchListView.this.arrad.getFilter().filter(arg0);

                    }
           });


        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is because you've added a `TextChangedListener` inside your `onClickListener`.

This means that when you click the button it will add a listener that  **waits for the text to change**.

You don't need this listener because your text has already changed.

Manipulate the SearchList from the `onClicklistener` itself

```
SearchListView.this.arrad.getFilter().filter(reqdString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, First of all Take out `addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()..` From button's click..

Put it in `onCreate()` of Activity.

Define Class level String variable

```
String filterString = "";
```

Now, in

```
@Override  
public void afterTextChanged( Editable arg0)  
{   
 filterString = arg0.toString();  
}
```

And button's `onClick()`

put only this line,

```
SearchListView.this.arrad.getFilter().filter(filterString);
```